Python Gitlab API get users by whether or not they have made a commit
At the company I work at we are trying to get a list of who is a developer in the company, but we need to do this based on whether or not the person has made a commit to GitLab rather than their access level. I know that you can get User objects from the python GitLab API and get attributes from that, I also know that you can get commit history from those users, but that is only for projects under their namespace. We need to get the users who have committed at all in the entire group. I found one solution, which is just to search the commits in each of the projects and then make a list of the unique users that are not bots, the problem is that there are a ton of groups, subgroups, and projects throughout the companies GitLab group so it means the run is taking forever. Am I missing something? Is there a way to get the commit history of the users for a specific group? Or will I just have to concede that it will take forever. Just trying to figure out if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Unless you are an administrator of a self-hosted or dedicated GitLab instance, you can only ascertain contributors on a per-repository basis via the API. You probably don't want to try enumerating all commits on each project though. Instead, use the repository contributors API which has this information compiled for you already.
There's also no particular reason using the API for this scenario must be slow. You can make requests to the API for separate projects concurrently, within established rate limits. For example, if you are using gitlab.com and have 10,000 projects, you can make up to 2,000 API calls per minute, so you could theoretically get all the contributor information you need within about 5 minutes after enumerating the group's projects which can be done (including recursively through subgroups) with the list projects API.

If you are an administrator of a self-hosted or dedicated instance, you can use the user activities API.
